# Postgres, jsonb & jsonb_set

Tags: json, postgresql

Depending on the HTTP_USER_AGENT I have to return a very specialized formatted version of a json structure to the client.

The json object is generated as usual with standard postgres functions.
Lets assume the generated json looks similar to this:

```
{
    "return_code" : 0,
    "payload" : {
        "name" : "smith",
        "age": 17,
        "address" :{
            "street" : "<whatever>",
            "city" : "<anycity>"
        }
    }
}
```

Now under some circumstances I have to return this json in the following format:

```
{
    "return_code" : 0,
    "payload" : "{"name" : "smith", "age": 17, "address" :"{"street" : "<whatever>", "city" : "<anycity>"}"}"
}
```

As you can see the nested payload object should be returned as a string - masking ignored here for better readability.

Further else the address property should also be returned as a string, not as a json object.

My postgres code that should do this is simply:

```
response := jsonb_set(response, '{payload}', to_jsonb((response->'payload')::text));
```

But the result from the code above looks like:

```
{
    "return_code" : 0,
    "payload" : "{"name" : "smith", "age": 17, "address" :{"street" : "<whatever>", "city" : "<anycity>"}}"
}
```

Consider the quotes are missing (just two) for the address-object.
How can I fix this?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you need a further level of escaping / quoting on the `address` property, because you have:

- Your substitution: `{ "payload" : { ... } }` -> `{ "payload" : "{ ... }" }`
- Extra substitution: `{ "address": { ... } }` -> `{ "address": "{ ... }" }`

You'll need to do this *before* the existing line, so I think what you want is this (requires an extra `jsonb` variable, `payload`):

```
payload := jsonb_set(response->'payload', '{address}', to_jsonb((response->'payload'->address)::text));
response := jsonb_set(response, '{payload}', to_jsonb(payload::text));
```

Comment: indeed, that should be possible. but this was just a sample. possible json structures returned can totally vary within the payload-object. I just want to make the conversion in a generic way after whatever structure has been created at the very end of the processing.

Comment: @CyrilDamm Then you need some definition of how the structure can vary - is it always at most two levels that need double-quoting? Or might you sometimes need `{ "foo": "{"bar": "{ "baz": "{ ... }" }" }" }`, or deeper recursion? Would inner arrays also need double-quoting? (Also, I dread to think what parser the other end needs recursive quoting like this; I can understand quoting the single `payload` section, but not sure why anything further would need to be manipulated.)